# Filtering MySQL query. "AND" operator

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting excessive rows selected from the db. However, when i try to filter the data with `AND lt_num` it does not select anything at all. What could be the problem?

```
$w = $_POST['pal_num'];
$w = "'".implode("','",$_POST['pal_num'])."'";
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_tab WHERE pal_num AND lt_num in (".$weights.");");
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `$w` in place of `$weights`?,  Where is `$weights` defined?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to use `$w` in place of `$weights`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to do two comparisons like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    pl_tab 
WHERE 
    pal_num in (".$weights.")
    AND lt_num in (".$weights.");
```

You can't say `column1 and column2 = 3` for example. If you want rows where both are equal to 3, you would need to use `column1=3 and column2=3` in your query.

Also, you might want to have a read of [this Q&A that I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) a while back which covers off a lot of basic SQL queries and expands from there.

Edit:

If you have `$weights` in the query, you do set it somewhere, or do you want it to be what is in your variables you show here:

```
$weights = $_POST['pal_num'];
$weights = "'".implode("','",$_POST['pal_num'])."'";
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: I changed it to `("SELECT * FROM pl_tab WHERE pal_num in (".$weights.") AND lt_num in (".$weights.");");` and it still doesn't work. Did i miss anything? Thank you for link, I definitely should read it.

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant. `$weights`, not `$w`